# iterating each string of sentences in a list at a time in python using one line for loop

Tags: python, string, list, loops

I have a list of strings of sentences like the following:

```
my_list= ["my name is X", "the house is far", "the place is cold"]
```

what I would like to do is to basically access one sentence as a string from this list each time using a for loop in one line.

I have tried:

```
sent = [[l for l in sen] for sen in my_list]
```

but it returns a list of lists of character strings.

so what i want is to access the sentences as strings one at a time with a one line for loop.

Comment: You don't need either list comprehension just use a normal for loop  - `for sen in my_list:`

Comment: Surely `for s in my_list:` "accesses the sentences as strings one at a time with a one line for loop". Since you already seem to know that lists are iterable, I don't think that your problem description matches what you really want to do. Please clarify by showing intended output.

Comment: Also, a list comprehension is not a one line for loop

Comment: Do you want this: `[[sen] for sen in my_list]` instead? Or words, like this: `[[l for l in sen.split()] for sen in list]`?

Comment: `for s in my_list: process(s)` can be put on one line (if `process(s)` is a single statement) if that is what you mean. But even though that is possible, it can make code harder to read.

Comment: so just to clarify, if I say my_list[2], it will return the third sentence as a string, now I want to instead get each sentence at a time as a string again with a for loop, and possibly a one line for loop

Comment: Your comment which begins "so just to clarify" makes the question less clear. Are you trying to iterate over the sentences in the list or are you trying to iterate over the words in the sentences? How does the simple `for s in my_list:` fail to do what you want?

Comment: @shaikmoeed The fact that you need to ask is enough to show that your answer is premature. The question is too vague to answer.

Comment: @JohnColeman Yes, according to the OP *but it returns a list of lists of character strings*, I thought OP want to remove nested lists or maybe trying to implement two for-loops in a single list comprehension. To make sure, about my guess, asking OP about the same.

Comment: @shaikmoeed my guess is that OP is trying to iterate over `[w for s in my_list for w in s.split()]`, but we shouldn't need to guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a nested comprehension for this. You can just use a single list comprehension:

```
sent = [do_something(sen) for sen in my_list]
```

Or with a normal for loop, if you don't have a need to make a new list:

```
for sen in my_list:
    do_something(sen)
```

The latter can also be done in one physical line:

```
my_list= ["my name is X", "the house is far", "the place is cold"]

for sen in my_list: print(sen)
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> my name is X
> the house is far
> the place is cold
> ```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but this will return the whole list. what I want is one sentence (as a string) at a time from this list

Comment: nothings wrong with that, was just wondering if it is possible in one line

Comment: List comprehension are for when you want to make a new list. There's no point in them if you simply want to run a function for every element without creating a new list.

Comment: well, I am not creating a new list. out of this list I only want to access each string of sentence at a time. so, when i say my_list[0], it will return the first sentence as string. but i want to do this in a for loop, and possiblly in one line